# Increase font size based on the iphone screen size

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

How to change font sizes automatically of all *buttons, label* title **based on the devices (iphone/ipad)** in the UIStoryboard? If i change in programmatically there are my different screen sizes how can i change for all the components. Is there any way to do that in proper way ?

Answer (score 3):

**Try This For Swift**

Create function.

```
func setCustomFont() -> CGFloat {

        //Current runable device/simulator width find
        let bounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
        let width = bounds.size.width

        // basewidth you have set like your base storybord is IPhoneSE this storybord width 320px.
        let baseWidth: CGFloat = 320

        // "14" font size is defult font size
        let fontSize = 14 * (width / baseWidth)

        return fontSize
    }
```

Use this function.

```
yourbutton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.init(name: "Helvetica", size: setCustomFont())
```

This type you also set **UILabel** and **UITextfield** font but this not use for **UIButton**.

1.Go to storyboard select UILabel/UITextfiled.

2.Go in **Attribute Inspector**

3.**Check** Dynamic Type option Automatically Adjust Font.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the interface builder you can set separate size classes for the elements and adjust accordingly

Comment: Can't understand, can you tell how ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use AutoShrink like this:

```
yourButton.titleLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.5;
yourButton.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
```

This won't adjust the font size bigger than we set.But it will increase based on phone size upto maximum size that we set.

Comment: but this is based on only the length of the font size